# Swap elements in a quicksort implementation in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, quicksort

I have a implemented a quicksort algorithm in JavaScript. It pushes the elements in to other arrays based on if the elements is larger or smaller then the pivot. It looks like this.

```
    function quickSort(array){
      if (array.length <= 1) return array;
        var left = [];
        var right = [];
        var equal = [];
        var pivot = (array.length / 2) | 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          if (array[i] > array[pivot]) {
            right.push(array[i]);
        } else if (array[i] < array[pivot]) {
            left.push(array[i]);
          } else {
            equal.push(array[i]);
          }
        }
        return quickSort(left).concat(equal, quickSort(right));
    }
          quickSort([3,46,78,90,48,32,13,6,45,87,32,56,45]);
```

But is there a way to just swap the elements in the array instead off just pushing elements into other arrays?

Comment: the first hit on google: https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/11/27/computer-science-in-javascript-quicksort/

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in comments, from https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/11/27/computer-science-in-javascript-quicksort/

Just create a function that takes the array as a reference, and the 2 positions.

```
function swap(items, firstIndex, secondIndex){
    var temp = items[firstIndex];
    items[firstIndex] = items[secondIndex];
    items[secondIndex] = temp;
}
```